# select many div tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the below code is for many div tag :

```
<div class="posts">
   <div id="ex">
       <ul class="ul">
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       </ul>
        </div>
   <div id="ex">
       <ul class="ul">
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       <li id="item"><a href="#">s</a></li>
       </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the below code is `jquery` code:

```
$(".ul li#item a").each(function(){
    $(".ul li#item a:gt(0)").toggle();
});
```

i want to when run the code just show the first of li not all them.
please help me

Comment: Use class instead of id, for e.g. `<li class="item">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the each function with `ul` .And remove the `id` name from the selector.Because id is a unique one .`hide()` all `li` element.Then call the `first().show()`. its visibile only the first element

**Updated**

> **Note***:Avoid the duplication of same id name .better use classname
>   instead of id for multiple selector

```js
$(".ul").each(function() {
  $(this).find('li').hide().first().show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
the below code is for many div tag :

<div class="posts">
  <div class="ex">
    <ul class="ul">
      <li><a href="#">see</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="ex">
    <ul class="ul">
      <li><a href="#">see</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">s</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are welcome @behnamhosseiniarani.Kindly mark as a answer its helpfull for future visitiors

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also short and sweet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li").hide();
   $("ul>li:first-of-type").show();

});
```